# Не работает поиск в MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, java-ee, jdbc

Отправляю запрос на поиск в MySQL в следующем коде:

```
public void findPosts(String search, int page, HashMap<Long, Post> map){
    try{
        openConnections();

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select p.id, p.title, p.subtitle, p.image, p.views, p.date from posts p" +
                " order by p.date" +
                " where p.title like '%"+search.trim().replace(" ", "%%")+"%'" +
                "  limit " + (page - 1) * 5 + ", 5");
        while (resultSet.next()){
            generatePost(map, resultSet);
        }



        ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery("select count(id) from posts where id >  "+lastRow +
                " and title like '%"+search.trim().replace(" ", "%%")+"%'");
        res.next();
        this.notDefaultRows = (page-1) * 5 + res.getInt(1);

    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        closeConnections();
    }
}
```

При работе кода выдается следующая ошибка MySQL Syntax:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an  error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'where p.title like '%а%'  limit 0, 5' at line 1
```

Что тут не так, я не понимаю, вроде всё должно работать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте порядок утверждений

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select p.id, p.title, p.subtitle, p.image, p.views, p.date from posts p" +
                    " where p.title like '%"+search.trim().replace(" ", 
                    " order by p.date" +
"%%")+"%'" +
                    "  limit " + (page - 1) * 5 + ", 5");
```